# Does anyone know what exception C06D007F means?

Tags: windows, sqlite, delphi, exception, c++builder

I keep getting **External exception C06D007F** whenever I try to manipulate a SQLite database using Embarcadero RAD Studio XE5.

I've installed the SQLite.dll in every place I can think of including the project's directory, as well as the `C:\Windows\System32 directory`.

No matter what I do, I get this exception.

Can anyone give me a clear explanation of what the exception means?

Comment: check this thread if it helps: http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.dbexpress/sqlite-external-exception-c06d00/1080718

Answer (score 0):

The Interwebz say to use the [amalgamation](http://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html) from SQLite, and that should fix the problem.  Let us know if that worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think different version (You need SQLite3  version 3.8.4.3 04/03/2014)

1. Download  from  http://www.sqlite.org/download.html
   Dll File : 'Precompiled Binaries for Windows'
                 sqlite-dll-win32-x86-3080403.zip(323.29 KiB)
2. Extraction File (sqlite-dll-win32-x86-3080403)
3. Copy and paste "sqlite3.dll"   (631KB)
   c:\Windows\System32
   c:\Windows\SysWOW64

Answer (score 0):

Old, but still happening on Tokyo (XE10), take the steps Tyler suggested but copy the new sqlite3.dll to Delphi folder instead.

eg: C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin